# "reason" : "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    
    "match": {
      "service.name": "myservice"
    },
  "exists": {"field": "metrics.notification.delayed"}}
}
```

When i execute above query, i find **"reason" : "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]"**.
Basically, I want documents with field **"metrics.notification.delayed"** existing and also with field:value matching **"service.name": "myservice"**. Can anyone help me with this query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using more than one query i.e. `match` and `exists`, you need to combine them using [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) as below,

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "service.name": "myservice"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "metrics.notification.delayed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```